# Почему возвращается ошибка? (клиент-сервер TCP)

Tags: c, клиент-сервер

Вот такой код(начало):

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <string.h>  
#include <conio.h>

#define PORTNUM 1500
WSADATA wsaData;
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int s,ns,pid,i,j,nport;
    char buf[80];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *hp;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsaData);
    hp=gethostbyname("127.0.0.1");
    if(!hp)
    {
        perror("Get host by name error.");
        getch();
        exit(1);
    }
       printf("serv_addr=localhost\n");
    memset(&serv_addr,0,sizeof(serv_addr));
    memmove(&serv_addr.sin_addr,hp->h_addr,hp->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_family=hp->h_addrtype;
    serv_addr.sin_port=htons(PORTNUM);
    if((s=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0))==-1)
    {
        perror("Socket error.");
        getch();
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("hp->h_length=%d\n",hp->h_length);
    fprintf(stderr,"Server address: %s\n",inet_ntoa(serv_addr.sin_addr));
    if(connect(s,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr))==-1)
    {
        perror("Connect error."); // **возвращает Error 0**
        getch();
        exit(1);
    }
```

Почему возвращается ошибка "error 0"?

Comment: Странно, но Ваш код у меня такого не печатает Соединяется с портом 1500 и заканчивается.

Comment: Мдя... Действительно, очень странно.

Comment: Значит порт "не занят", на нем не висит ни какого IP-сервиса.

Comment: Эм... А как узнать на каком порте висит? В общем какие порт там можно использовать?

Comment: @oleg_ismailov, а с каким, собственно, сервером Ваш клиент собирается общаться?

Вот его и надо запустить на порт 1500.

Comment: А шайтан его знает... Это лабораторная работа. Написать клиент. А сервером выступает сам комп.

Comment: А сам по себе комп это делать не умеет.

Comment: >Это лабораторная работа. Написать клиент. А сервером выступает сам комп

По всей видимости, Вам предлагается написать и сам сервер. Либо смотрите, спрашивайте дополнительную информацию по задаче.

Comment: В линуксе можно легко сделать простой echo-сервер

    ncat -l -e /bin/cat свой-IP-addr 1500

на порту 1500

Comment: >WSAStartup

 --  

>сделать простой echo-сервер

и разместить его для начала на VM :)

Comment: http://joncraton.org/blog/46/netcat-for-windows

Comment: @alexlz, [`netcat`](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) - юниксовая приблуда, а то, что на `win` есть много nix-аналогов я вкурсе :) То же самое можно и в `cygwin` запустить. Просто сделал акцент на том, что клиент ТС виндовый.

Comment: @mega Так VM-то зачем?

Comment: В общем, спасибо, проблема решена)